# Beautiful Soup - scraping empty values

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some Python code which scrapes the game logs of NBA players for a given season (for instance: [the data here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01/gamelog/1991/)) into a `csv` file. I'm using Beautiful Soup. I am aware that there is an option to just get `csv` version by clicking on a link on the website, but I am adding something to each line, so I feel like scraping line by line is the easiest option. The goal is to eventually write code that does this for every season of every player.

The code looks like this:

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getData(url):
    html = urllib.urlopen(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    type(soup)

    file = open('/Users/Mika/Desktop/a_players.csv', 'a')
    for table in soup.find_all("pre", class_ = ""):
        dataline = table.getText
        player_id = player_season_url[47:-14]
        file.write(player_id + ',' + dataline + '\n')
    file.close()

player_season_url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01/gamelog/1991/"
getData(player_season_url)
```

The problem is this: as you can see from inspecting the element of the URL, some cells in the table have empty values.

```
<td class="right " data-stat="fg3_pct"></td>
```

(this is an example of a good cell with a value ("1") in in that is properly scraped):

```
<th scope="row" class="right " data-stat="ranker" csk="1">1</th>
```

When scraping, the rows come out uneven, skipping over the empty values to create a `csv` file with the values out of place. Is there a way to ensure that those empty values get replaces with `" "` in the `csv` file?

Comment: You should add a few lines of html to your question to make your [mcve] complete - format it as code.. The example html should have a mixture of *good* cells and *bad* cells.

Comment: And you can't add to the csv after if downloaded by link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For writing csv files Python has builtin support (module `csv`). For grabbing whole table from the page you could use script like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re

def getData(url):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'lxml')

    player_id = re.findall(r'(?:/[^/]/)(.*?)(?:/gamelog)', url)[0]

    with open('%s.csv' % player_id, 'w') as f:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        d = [[td.text for td in tr.find_all('td')] for tr in soup.find('div', id='all_pgl_basic').find_all('tr') if tr.find_all('td')]
        for row in d:
            csvwriter.writerow([player_id] + row)

player_season_url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdelal01/gamelog/1991/"
getData(player_season_url)
```

Output is in CSV file (I added from LibreOffice):

[image]

Edit:

- extracted player_id from URL
- file is saved in {player_id}.csv

Comment: This works, but it doesn't add the player_id to each row like i had in my original code

Comment: I'm getting a invalid syntax error on line 11, 

`line 11
    with open(f'{player_id}.csv', 'w') as f:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]`

Comment: I have 2.7. I received another error: `line 18, in <module>
    getData(player_season_url)
  File "/Users/Mika/Desktop/ex.py", line 9, in getData
    player_id = re.search(r'(?:/[^/]/)(.*?)(?:/gamelog)', url)[1]
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`